# React state not changing on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

so I've recently started to learn react from Udemy, I wrote this code which dynamically changes the state of the page when a button is clicked. The tutor has the same code and his code works perfectly fine but mine doesn't. May I know what's wrong?

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';


class App extends Component {

  state = {
    persons: [
      {name : 'Honey', age : 23},
      {name : 'Test', age: 19},
      {name : 'Test2', age: 21}
    ],
    otherState : 'Hmm'
  }

//edit

  switchPersonHandler = () => {
    this.setState = ( {
      persons: [
        {name : 'Honey', age : 23},
        {name : 'Ahhh', age: 19},
        {name : 'Change this', age: 21}
      ]
    } )
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React :)</h1>
        </header>
        <button onClick={this.switchPersonHandler}>Switch Name</button>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[0].name} age={this.state.persons[0].age}/>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[1].name} age={this.state.persons[1].age}/>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[2].name} age={this.state.persons[2].age}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my persons.js

```
import React from 'react'

const person = (props) => {
return  <div>
            <p>My name is {props.name} and my age is {props.age}</p>
        </div>

}

export default person;
```

So, what I want to do is when t he button is clicked, they persons object gets dynamically merged and updated content is showed on the web page. 
Also, pardon me if this is a bad question, I'm really new to this.

Comment: It's `this.setState({ persons: [...] })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which you can use, click on `Run this snippet` to see how it works:

Changes to be made:

1- change `person` component with lower case `p` to `Person`

2- `this.setState` is a function and you need to pass the `state` as an argument

```js
function Person(props){
return  (<div>
            <p>My name is {props.name} and my age is {props.age}</p>
        </div>)

}

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    persons: [
      {name : 'Honey', age : 23},
      {name : 'Test', age: 19},
      {name : 'Test2', age: 21}
    ],
    otherState : 'Hmm'
  }


  switchPersonHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      persons: [
        {name : 'working', age : 23},
        {name : 'Ahhh', age: 19},
        {name : 'Change this', age: 21}
      ]
    })
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React :)</h1>
        </header>
        <button onClick={this.switchPersonHandler}>Switch Name</button>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[0].name} age={this.state.persons[0].age}/>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[1].name} age={this.state.persons[1].age}/>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[2].name} age={this.state.persons[2].age}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. The issue was I was using " = " sign with setState, I probably confused myself with new and old syntax.